# Will a verbal ban from Spain 30+ years ago prevent my husband from taking a cruise out of Barcelona?

Tags: visas, spain, applications, visa-bans

My husband was arrested 30 years ago in Spain while serving in the military, stayed one year on base and was "told" never to come back to Spain. This happened in his early 20's and they kept him on base, not in a Spanish prison.  He did not get anything official, just someone saying never to come back to Spain.

Fast forward to "He grew up" and is now 57 with a sick wife... we want to cruise on the Mediterranean, but everything that we are interested in is out of Barcelona. Is he indeed banned or is there a way to find out?

---

Additional info provided by the OP in a comment...

> He was about to leave to go home after serving in the Navy for 4
>   years...less than 24 hours before he was to leave, they all went to a
>   party, and the locals had hash there, he was not found in possession
>   but arrested and had to stay on base for one year in Spain and then go
>   home. All we want to do is go on a cruise and they all take off out of
>   Spain

Comment: He should simply apply for a Schengen visa. I doubt he will have any problems. This was before the Schengen system so requesting information from [them](https://www.tlscontact.com/lb2ch/upload/sis_lb2ch.pdf) will be futile, there will be nothing there. Unless he killed someone or committed some particularly grievous felony like rape, whatever ban he had is looooong expired.

Comment: Just go and enjoy your cruise. If your husband was truly dangerous they would never have allowed him to escape prison. A simple bar fight (or whatever the misdemeanor was) is not enough to trigger a lifelong ban.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie Applying for a Schengen visa won't be useful (or even possible at all) if one isn't needed in the first place.

Comment: Whose military was he serving in?  Whose base was he was "kept" on?  Was the person who told him never to return acting in an official capacity?  If so, on behalf of what organization?  What was his position?

Comment: If he's expecting problems, the simplest way to get reassurance is to apply for a Schengen visa in advance.

Comment: What is his nationality? In General, if he's a visa-free national and does **not** enter the Schengen Area through Spain, I can't imagine there being any issues, seeing as Spain doesn't have border checks coming from other Schengen states

Comment: @GayotFow it is not clear to me that Schengen consulates will issue Schengen visas to those who do not require them.  Do you know of any case where that has happened?  If so, do you know whether all consulates of all Schengen countries will entertain such applications?

Comment: @phoog please see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91990/flight-transfer-via-ireland-with-a-uk-reentry-ban at the bottom of the answer

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie why would you edit "..." , an ellipsis, to ".." which is just a punctuation error?

Comment: @KateGregory I got distracted and didn't finish my edit.

Comment: What sort of offense was he charged with in the first place? Was this something like rape or firearm trafficking or was it more like second degree jaywalking with intent to deface a postage stamp?

Comment: Again kitkat, please tell us his nationality

Comment: Apply for a travel visa. if it's accepted, congratulations, he's not banned. Said that, a verbal ban given by american authorities on the Rota naval base in 1987 might not have any legal backing at all on spanish soil, and might be just an internal reprimend.

Answer (score 6):

For the part about asking for your husbands alerts under the EU transparency regulations, data retention comes in to play in a way that may be beneficial to him.  [Regulation (EC) No 1987/2006](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32006R1987) has this to say...

> Alerts for the purpose of refusing entry or stay should not be kept
>   longer in SIS II than the time required to fulfil the purposes for
>   which they were supplied. As a general principle, they should be
>   automatically erased from SIS II after a period of three years. Any
>   decision to keep an alert for a longer period should be based on a
>   comprehensive individual assessment. Member States should review these
>   alerts within this three-year period and keep statistics about the
>   number of alerts the retention period of which has been extended.

Spain joined the Schengen regime in 1991, 4 years after your husband's (alleged) offence. If they entered an alert at that time it would have expired in 1994. Otherwise we have to accept the *palpably ridiculous* case that they entered an alert in 2015 for an offence that occurred in 1987 and for which there were no judicial proceedings and no indications in his passport.  Biometrics did not exist in a real way until the mid 2000's and this further removes the likelihood of a problem.

Note that in all events your husband will still need to qualify as a short-stay visitor.

Comment: "Should your husband opt for this strategy, he may wish to consider applying for a transit visa instead" There are no Schengen transit (B) visas anymore, only short-stay (C) visas with the option of ticking "transit" as the trip purpose in the application form if that's the case

Comment: In this scenario, what would be the purpose of visa application in your mind? Why not make use of the right to information mentioned in article 42 of regulation 1987/2006 instead of attracting an automatic refusal (in the off chance that there is indeed a ban and alert in the SIS)?

Comment: @Relaxed It seems (with emphasis on seems) to have occurred to Gayot (in part due to the advice of a professional contact of his) that, like in the UK, the solution to immigration-related issues in Schengen is to successfully obtain a visa. Which is not the case.

Comment: OK, so I see you chose to alter your answer without clearly answering my question. It is true that merely requesting information does not clear anything from the record *but neither does applying for a visa*. The Schengen Visa Code is very explicit about that, if there is indeed an alert for the purpose of refusing entry, it should result in a refusal of any visa application.

Comment: He was about to leave to go home after serving in the Navy for 4 years...less than 24 hours before he was to leave, they all went to a party, and the locals had hash there, he was not found in possession but arrested and had to stay on base for one year in Spain and then go home.  All we want to do is go on a cruise and they all take off out of Spain

Comment: @KitKat ***who arrested him?***  If he was arrested e.g. by the US military then really there is no issue at all.  ***What is his nationality?***  If he is e.g. British or Irish, then there's even less than an issue.

Comment: So you're evading once again… why is this ever changing answer with demonstrably false info getting upvotes? The last version is nonsense and irrelevant. Apart from everything else, it was clear from the beginning that a 30-year ban was exceedingly unlikely. Schengen countries extend 10 or 20-year bans only in very serious cases. If that's all you had to say, you don't need to babble about visa applications, best practices or the SIS regulation.

Comment: But when there is a 10-year ban (and they do exists), then the entry gets refreshed every three years. That's a techincal, routine procedure. There is nothing in the regulation forbidding it and the fact that data is retained for three years is neither here nor there. That's just the ways the regulation works.

Comment: Incidentally, I note that usually you love quoting people in absurd ways and turning your answers into some sort of forum thread when that's completely unnecessary but in this case it seems my (and Crazydre's) comments prompted you to completely revise your answer and make it entirely about a regulation you hadn't thought of mentioning before I cited it… and you haven't even acknowledged them. Classy!

Answer (score 4):

**If he's an EU/EFTA national:**
He's covered by the freedom of movement and cannot be refused entry into Spain except on serious security-related grounds. In fact, unless travelling from outside the Schengen Area, there won't be any border checks going to Spain.

**If he's a visa-free non-EU/EFTA national:**
Enter the Schengen Area through Portugal or France to be nauseatingly safe. Given that this ban dates back to the pre-Schengen days, it is not something that's going to be recorded in the SIS (common Schengen blacklist); that is, if it's even in the Spanish national blacklist in the first place, which is unlikely given that Schengen bans today last up to 20 years, plus biometrics weren't captured back in those days. Between France/Portugal and Spain, there are no border checks.

**If he's a visa national:**
When applying for a Schengen visa at the Spanish embassy, his fingerprints will be matched against national databases, and you'll know whether the ban's still in force.

Others answerers have suggested applying for a Schengen visa even if you're visa-free, for the purpose of establishing your husband's status. However, it would be worth first consulting the Spanish embassy and asking how they can establish your husband's status. Maybe a visa application isn't a necessary step at all, and I see no reason to ***assume*** it is - Schengen embassies are not as "closed" as their UK counterparts.

Comment: For all we know, the husband could be an EU national.

Comment: @phoog Hence my question about his nationality